# If-Else statement not printing results

Tags: c, if-statement

I am trying to plug in negative values, positive values, and zero into this program, and although I do get a printed result for the first two, whenever I type `0`, I get no response. The command prompt simply ends the program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void)
{

    int n, b;
    float add;
    int frac;
    float sum=0.0;

    printf("Enter n(1): "); scanf("%d", &n);

    if(n>0)
    {
        for(add = 0; add <= n; add ++)
        {
            sum += add;

        }
        printf("The sum of integers from 1 to %d is %f\n", n, sum); 

    }

    else if(n < 0)
    {
        b=abs(n);
        for(frac = 1; frac <= b; frac ++)
        {
            sum += (1.0f)/(float)frac;
        }

        printf("The sum of integers from 1 to 1/%d is %f\n", b, sum);   

    }

    else
    {
        printf("For n = 0, the sum is 0.0\n");
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: The if-else statement don't say what to do for `n==0`. You only specified for `n>0` and `n<0`, which don't include 0. (edit: wrong answer, my bad, I hadn't scroll down)

Comment: @tmoreau Oh ok, I simply assumed that with everything greater than zero and everything less than zero covered, the only other value left would be zero.

Comment: @tmoreau , The OP has an `else` statement which will take care when `n==0`.

Comment: Oh no wait, I hadn't scroll down. It should go into `else`

Comment: @tmoreau but he specified `else` so he don't need to specify for `n==0` or am I wrong?

Comment: @Jetuas There doesn't seem to be any problem. Perhaps you need a `getchar()` just before the `return 0;`?

Comment: Huh, I tried "else if (n==0)", and I still got no printed result...I'm not sure what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Side remark: don't use `float` as the loop variable to avoid floating point arithmetic issues.

Comment: @CoolGuy tried that, though it also didn't change anything.

Comment: @AlexD will keep that in mind!

Comment: Odd. What compiler and / or IDE are you using? Are you sure you are running the exact program given? Which OS are you on?

Comment: posted code does not show any bug.

Comment: @CoolGuy I'm using DevC++, which I'm assuming is well known compiler?  And yeah, it's the exact same!  I'm running windows 8.1...

Comment: Related to tmoreau's comment "Oh no wait, I hadn't scroll down. It should go into `else`" - This is a good reason why you shouldn't put a blank line before an `else` statement. Take out those blank lines so it is more clear that each `else` is connected to the `if` or `else if` above.

Comment: You mean just program simply exits from console?

Comment: @MichaelGeary noted!

Comment: @Jetuas  It give correct output when `n` is `0` . It doesn't seen to have any problem.

Comment: @Jetuas DevC++ is an IDE, if i'm not mistaken. GCC is probably the compiler. Again, the posted code doesn't seem to have any problem. Try two `getchar()`s before `return 0;`.

Comment: When I compiled I got the ouput, may be just use getch(); before return 0;....

Comment: @ameyCU Yeah..I have no idea wtf is going on...

Comment: @Jetuas And since you are on windows, try adding `getch()` before `return 0;`.

Comment: @Jetuas  Did you mean when you run `.exe`  one or through the `cmd`?

Comment: @CoolGuy Oh ok! Uh, tried that...still no luck o_O  Haha, I think i'll just give up on this one :P .

Comment: @ameyCU through the cmd

Comment: @Jetuas I'm out of ideas....Try formatting your PC :p Or maybe try Code::Blocks instead of DevC++

Comment: @CoolGuy yeah, I don't think I can afford to spend too much time on this one issue tho :P (every other program runs perfectly).  Will try Code::Blocks later though.  Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: 1) There's no need to cast `frac` to float because it'll be done automatically. 2) Only 2 cases is needed: (if) `n >= 0` and (else) `n < 0`. 3) When n > 0 use `b = -n` instead of `b = abs(n)

Comment: @Jetuas is your issue solved?i just checked your code and its working correctly

Comment: @aa1992 Well, it didn't work on my computer, so I tried it on a friend's computer, and it works perfectly there...so it's suffice to say something is wrong with my computer :P

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try

```
    if ( n > 0 ) {
       //...
    } else {
       if ( n < 0 ) {
          //...
       } else {
          //...
       }
    }
```

EDIT: You can always `return` from main earlier:

```
    if ( n > 0 ) {
       //...
       return 0;
    } else if ( n < 0 ) {
       //...
       return 0;
    }
    // program reaches this line only when n == 0
```